# Ceiling fan wiring, fan 2 runs slower

Tags: wiring

I have 2 fans on one switch , wired from switch to fan #1 then to fan #2 - fan #2 runs slower do I need a higher amp switch

Comment: Are the fans multi-speed? A lot fans are 3-speed and you can use a pull-chain (or a remote on the newfangled ones) to select the speed. Perhaps the two fans have two different speeds selected?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in all boxes involved please?

Comment: Are they the same model of fan? Are they controlled by a remote?

Comment: My bet is on @statuephemism 's answer. I replaced a ceiling fan once because it was slow, only to find out that the remote control and pull chain operated different mechanisms. The remote works on a percentage of whatever the pull chain is set to, and mine was on medium.

Answer (score 1):

If the fans are run in parallel then they should run the same speed.
If, however, you (accidentally) wired them in series, they will run slower and they can end up running at different speeds depending on the motor and the drag.

Comment: Although I agree I would not expect the fans to work at 1/2 voltage and that’s what each fan would have in series.

Comment: It all depends on the torque required.  Most likely the lower voltage will starve the fans for power and (as you mentioned) they might not even have enough power to start.  It is Actually even possible for them to run at full speed with the lower voltage since the target speed of an AC induction motor is set by the AC frequency rather than the voltage; but it would need to have a pretty light load (like if the fan blades weren't on).